# VS Code: avoid overaggressive parenthesis removal (in Scala / Metals)

Tags: visual-studio-code, autocomplete

I don't think this is a Scala- or Metals-specific issue, but that's where I'm seeing it.

VS Code aggressively removes parentheses, but not in a symmetric fashion. For instance, if I type the following:

[image: Before image, two sets of parentheses]

and I want to remove the inside parentheses, I would start by removing the inner closing parenthesis:

[image: closing inner parenthesis removed]

OK, the highlighting is already suggesting the problem: when I removed the *inner* parenthesis, it is the *outer* one that looks unmatched.

If I now go ahead and remove the *inner opening parenthesis*, **both the opening and closing parentheses are lost**:

[image: mismatched with only opening outer parenthesis remaining]

---

So maybe there is a **right way** to remove them that I am missing.  Instead of removing the inside closing parenthesis, I will start by removing the inside *opening* parenthesis:

[image]

Unfortunately, in this case *only* the inner opening parenthesis is removed, so it is still mismatched.

#### Ugly Workaround

So for now, I either remove the inner *closing* parenthesis, then the inner opening parenthesis (which removes both, as shown), then I *go back and add the lost closing parenthesis)*.  Or, I remove the inner *opening* parenthesis, then go to the end of the line and remove that extra closing parenthesis.

Because I'll do this hundreds of times a day, the few wasted keystrokes really add up.

What did VS Code want us to do here?  What is the right way to engage with its parenthesis autodeletion?

Comment: FWIW I am not seeing this in a javascript file, so maybe it is a language-specific issue.

Comment: I opened up https://vscode.dev, installed the Scala language extension, then tried this. I did not get the same behavior. Maybe your settings messed it up (online VSCode has default settings) :/

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be normal behavior. The parenthesis match the last open. When you remove the right inner, what was the right outer becomes the closing to the left inner. Then when you remove the left inner, there is nothing between so it removes the set.Like when you type an open and it types the close for you.

This behaves differently in different languages, below is CPP, If I remove the left outer, the right outer becomes the left. If you go to settings and search auto, you will see it is language defined. Changing it to never or always will override the languages setting and should produce what you want.

[image: Fig A]
[image: Fig B]